# mapbox map matching API returning very low coordinates compared to google maps roads API

Tags: mapbox

We are currently using google and trying to switch to mapBOX, but for the same coordinates Mapbox is returning very low coordinates compared to google, which is not enough to build road maps, it's just drawing straight lines.

Comment: What is a low coordinate?

Comment: less number of coordinates compared to google.

Answer (score 0):

We eventually figured out that MapBOX uses open street maps for map-matching, which uses low quality, outdated maps, which don't show all the roads that google have in their system. that's why mapbox is returning less number of coordinates compared to google.

so basically mapbox is not good for non-city areas and not good for use outside the USA locations.